# what exactly is number in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I have to get the union of types of values that belong to numeric key then we have to use `number`.

[`TS PLAYGROUND`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhmAlgWzgGwjAvDA2gcgBMQBzfAGhn2DigqoAsBTMfAXXk1EigCgoAngAcmMAIJJUabDEEiQAM3iT0EXGACuyAEZMAThwD0h2cNESU6GQCJiJazAA%20MazSgPn15mGu8gA)

```
const animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'hen'] as const
type Animal = typeof animals[number] // type Animal = "dog" | "cat" | "hen"
```

But what exactly is this `number`. A `type`, `constant`, `keyword` or what?

Comment: A type. See linked duplicate.

Comment: It's a (built-in) type.  Parse it as `(typeof animals)[number]`.  You're [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) an array type with `number`, meaning you get the type of the properties of the array at numeric indices... that is, a union of its element types.

Answer (score 0):

A `number` is a type representing JavaScript floats in TypeScript.

[More information in TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#number)